# sweetalert2 should redirecting to another html after clicking OK

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

**Not showing alert, as well redirecting is not working**

```
        //sweetalert2
        swal({
            title: "Success!",
            text: "Agent Created Successfully.",
            type: "success",
        }.then(function(){
            alert('here');
            window.location.href = "example.html";
        }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your paren is misplaced:

```
    //sweetalert2
    swal({
        title: "Success!",
        text: "Agent Created Successfully.",
        type: "success",
    }).then(function(){
        alert('here');
        window.location.href = "example.html";
    });
```